# Why doesn't python Queue have falsey behavior

Tags: python, queue

In python, I have gotten quite used to container objects having truthy behavior when they are populated, and falsey behavior when they are not:

```py
# list
a = []
not a
True

a.append(1)
not a
False

# deque
from collections import deque
d = deque()
not d
True

d.append(1)
not d
False

# and so on
```

However, [queue.Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue) does not have this behavior. To me, this seems odd and a contradiction against almost any other container data type that I can think of. Furthermore, the method `empty` on queue seem to go against coding conventions that avoid race conditions on any other object (checking if a file exists, checking if a list is empty, etc). For example, we would generally say the following is bad practice:

```py
_queue = []

if not len(_queue):
    # do something
```

And should be replaced with

```py
_queue = []

if not _queue:
    # do something
```

or to handle an `IndexError`, which we might still argue would be better with the `if not _queue` statement:

```py
try:
    x = _queue.pop()
except IndexError as e:
    logger.exception(e)
    # do something else
```

Yet, `Queue` requires someone to do one of the following:

```py
_queue = queue.Queue()

if _queue.empty():
    # do something
    # though this smells like a race condition


# or handle an exception
try:
    _queue.get(timeout=5)
except Empty as e:
    # do something else
    # maybe logger.exception(e)
```

Is there documentation somewhere that might point to *why* this design choice was made? It seems odd, especially when [the source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/queue.py) shows that it was built on top of `collections.deque` (noted that Queue does *not* inherit from `deque`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the definition of the [truth value testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) procedure, the behavior is expected:

> Any object can be tested for truth value, for use in an if or while
>   condition or as operand of the Boolean operations below.
>
> By default, an object is considered true unless its class defines
>   either a `__bool__()` method that returns False or a `__len__()` method
>   that returns zero, when called with the object.

As Queue does not neither implements `__bool__()` nor `__len__()` then it's truth value is `True`. As to why does Queue does not implement `__len__()` a clue can be found in the comments of the qsize function:

> '''Return the approximate size of the queue (not reliable!).'''

The same can be said of the `__bool__()` function.

Comment: I think his question was really "why did the author decide to implement Queue this way?"

Comment: @JohnGordon probability because consulting for the length of the queue is an approximate operation as specified in the comments of qsize.

Comment: Looking into the implementation of `qsize`, however, we can see that there is an acquisition of a mutex when `len` is called on the internal `deque`. Is it not reliable in that the state is not guaranteed once the context manager concludes and the mutex is released?

Comment: @C.Nivs I guess so, I cannot be sure you can find a more detailed in the docs.

Comment: I suppose [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.qsize) might answer that question. I would imagine it would be more reliable to just handle the exception, since direct access is better than doing a check for state that might not hold

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to leave the accepted answer as is, but as far as I can tell, the reason is that `if _queue: # do something` *would* be a race condition, since `Queue` is designed to be passed between threads and therefore possesses dubious state as far as tasks go.

From the source:

```py
class Queue:
    ~snip~

    def qsize(self):
        '''Return the approximate size of the queue (not reliable!).'''
        with self.mutex:
            return self._qsize()


    def empty(self):
        '''Return True if the queue is empty, False otherwise (not reliable!).
        This method is likely to be removed at some point.  Use qsize() == 0
        as a direct substitute, but be aware that either approach risks a race
        condition where a queue can grow before the result of empty() or
        qsize() can be used.
        To create code that needs to wait for all queued tasks to be
        completed, the preferred technique is to use the join() method.
        '''
        with self.mutex:
            return not self._qsize()

~snip
```

Must have missed this helpful docstring when I was originally looking. The `qsize` bool is not tied to the state of the queue once it's evaluated. So the user is doing processing against a queue based on an already out-of-date state.

Like checking the existence of a file, it's more pythonic to just handle the exception:

```py
try:
    task = _queue.get(timeout=4)
except Empty as e:
    # do something
```

since the exception/success against `get` *is* the state of the queue.

Likewise, we would not do:

```py
if os.exists(file):
    with open(file) as fh:
        # do processing
```

Instead, we would do:

```py
try:
    with open(file) as fh:
        # do processing
except FileNotFoundError as e:
    # do something else
```

I suppose the intentional leaving-out of the `__bool__` method by the author is to steer the developer *away* from leaning against such a paradigm, and treating the queue like you would any other object that might be of questionable state.